# Generic function to create table SQL query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I need a generic function that can insert values in table. How can I do this with variable number of arguments.

For example:

```
def create_table(self, tb_name, *args):
        sqlite3.connect(self.db_name).cursor().execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users")
        sqlite3.connect(self.db_name).cursor().execute("CREATE TABLE users(*args[0], *args[1], ....*args[n])")
```

1. *args[0] is 'name'  *args[1] is 'password'
2. *args[0] is 'name'  *args[1] is 'password' *args[2] is 'email'

Function must works in both ways.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless SQLite defaults to text, the `CREATE` DDL command in SQL requires data type with named columns. How do you pass that data type  list into function?

Comment: Why not use a ready-made solution, like SQLAlchemy or PonyORM? They have all of this sorted out, and are nicely declarative.

Comment: If you are doing this in Python as tagged why not creating your string `"CREATE TABLE users(*args[0], *args[1], ....*args[n])"` dynamically with string concatenation and the `%` operator?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a `join` to concatenate all items in list into one statement. Below assumes `TEXT` type for all *args*:

```
def create_table(self, tb_name, *args):
    vars = " TEXT,".join(*args) + " TEXT"

    sqlite3.connect(self.db_name).cursor().execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users")
    sqlite3.connect(self.db_name).cursor().execute("CREATE TABLE users ({})".format(vars))

# CREATE TABLE users (name TEXT, password TEXT)
# CREATE TABLE users (name TEXT, password TEXT, email TEXT)
```